# The different way to obtain URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, nsurl

In order to obtain URL, I usually follow this way.

```
    NSString *userText = urlText.text;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:userText];
```

Of coursely, urlText is linked with UITextField.

However, Recently, I saw this code in audioStreaming program.
([This is the program.](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer))

```
NSString *escapedValue =
    [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, (CFStringRef)downloadSourceField.text, NULL, NULL, 
                                                         kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedValue];
```

downloadSourceField is linked with UITextField.

What is diffence between these two methodes?
When I replaced the second method (escapedValue = ~~~ ) with (escapedValue = downloadSourceField.text;), the program worked well.
Could you let me know what is difference?
And What is the best method to obtain URL for **streaming**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method will percent-escape some characters which are typically not allowed in URLs. As an example, the space character is not allowed and will be encoded as %20. NSURL does not support passing a string containing a non-allowed character which has not been escaped to +URLWithString:, therefore passing the string through CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes first will let you support such URLs.

Answer (score 0):

interesting,

however, digging in the NSString docs you find these two functions:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

I think those are the "official" way of doing this